# How to make a Plus sign in XAML in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, polygon

How to make a Plus Sign in WPF using Polygon?

```
<Polygon Points="?,? ?,? ?,? ?,?" Fill="Green"></Polygon>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to using `Path`:

```
 <Path Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100"
      Fill="Green"   
      Data="M4.1561281,2.2702953 L4.8524521,2.2702954 4.8509674,3.963097 5.8969377,3.9630803 5.8969378,5.0916036 4.8524628,5.1061913 4.8524521,6.7843885 4.1561281,6.7843887 4.1559771,5.0877741 3.1116421,5.0916036 3.1116421,3.9630803 4.1556735,3.9654722 4.1561281,2.2702953 z"/>
```

This `Path` you can easily edit in Blend using "Direct Selection".

Polygon example:

```
<Viewbox Width="50" Height="50">
    <Polygon Name="myPolygon" Fill="Green" ></Polygon>
</Viewbox>
```

Code-behind:

```
myPolygon.Points = new PointCollection()
{
    new Point(4.1561279296875,2.27029538154602),
    new Point(4.85245227813721,2.27029538154602),
    new Point(4.85096740722656,3.9630970954895),
    new Point(5.89693784713745,3.96308040618896),
    new Point(5.89693784713745,5.09160375595093),
    new Point(4.85246276855469,5.10619115829468),
    new Point(4.85245227813721,6.78438854217529),
    new Point(4.1561279296875,6.78438854217529),
    new Point(4.15597724914551,5.0877742767334),
    new Point(3.11164212226868,5.09160375595093),
    new Point(3.11164212226868,3.96308040618896),
    new Point(4.15567350387573,3.96547222137451),
    new Point(4.1561279296875,2.27029538154602)
};
```

Comment: @user_47 check my answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually we create "plus signs" for buttons like "+" or "add new item button".
There is a full example of code for this this case:

The button Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}"
           x:Key="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    Value="0.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="DimGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ButtonBase}}"
           x:Key="StyleButtonAddNewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Data="M 8,00 12,00 12,8 12,8 20,8 20,12 12,12 12,20 8,20 8,12 0,12 0,8 8,8 Z"
                          Stretch="UniformToFill"
                          Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="LimeGreen" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="DarkGreen" />
            </Trigger>     <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonAddNewItem"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Height="20"
                                    Width="20"
                                    Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonAddNewItem}" />
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The usage of this button:

```
 <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonAddNewItem"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Height="20"
                                    Width="20"
                                    Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonAddNewItem}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely I wouldn't use a Polygon but two lines:

```
    <Grid>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="50" X2="100" Y2="50" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="10"/>
        <Line X1="50" Y1="0" X2="50" Y2="100" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="10"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me - nothing was displayed. Perhaps this was because I've got a custom width on my button..

To get any resizable XAML icon, just use [Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com)

The particular solution for the plus sign is:

```
<Path Width="38" Height="38" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 35,19L 41,19L 41,35L 57,35L 57,41L 41,41L 41,57L 35,57L 35,41L 19,41L 19,35L 35,35L 35,19 Z "/>
```

To resize the icon, change the height and width, and change the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top proportionally.

eg.

`<Button>
    <Path Width="19" Height="19" Canvas.Left="9.5" Canvas.Top="9.5" .../>
 </Button>`